# Does a View created by joining two tables reads unqueried/unused columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

*Regarding this oversimplified example:*

In this database scheme

```
+--------------+  +-------------------+
| MASTER_TABLE |  |    FILES_TABLE    |
+-----+--------+  +-----+------+------+
| nID | field  |  | nID | meta | BLOB |
+-----+--------+  +-----+------+------+
|  1  | ...    |  |  1  |  ... | ...  |
+-----+--------+  +-----+------+------+
```

if I create a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT master.*, file.meta 
FROM master_table master
LEFT JOIN files_table file
USING (nid)
```

**does the unused column BLOB gets read when querying `myView`?** (read as: will it be much slower to query the view rather than querying the master_table only)

I'm asking this because column BLOB will be used to store files. The reason we split the table in two in the first place was to speed up the queries of master_table.

---

### **DISCLAIMER:**

When designing the data structure **it was decided by the project manager that the files annexed to the data should be stored in the database** rather than in the filesystem.

I'm quite aware of the numerous inflamed discussions regarding storing files in the database vs filesystem but, as I said, **it was not decided by me nor I have the power to change the decision.**

Comment: make sure you run the select statement thru EXPLAIN to confirm a key is being used

Comment: Are you under the mistaken impression that accessing a table reads columns that aren't mentioned anywhere in the query? It doesn't matter whether you use a view or an ordinary query, unused columns are never read.

Comment: @Barmar The MySQL documentation is not explicit in this and I confess I'm a beginner in the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only the fields listed in the select needed for the query that builds the view  are 'read'.  However, any join will affect the select time vs. just a single table select statement.

Since you're not using the blob field in the view, you wont' take this hit.

If `nid` is indexed in both the `master` and `file` tables, performance should be fairly good.

Optimal performance on this view's JOIN  would be if you had a composite index of (nid, meta) on the `file` table.  This assume meta isn't too big to be part of a composite index.

Comment: Meta here represents more than one column, although that number is smaller than 16 (composite index column limit). That suggestion might actually be a good idea, although I have to check if those values are "unique" enough to constitute a good index.

Comment: @Tivie the point of the meta being in the composite index isn't to speed up by increasing cardnality of index, but to avoid a second point lookup by primary key of the non-index original table.  All index lookups eventually perform a point lookup on the original table by PK unless all values needed in query are part of the index.  Hence composite indexes that cover for a query.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that. That info is actually very useful.